# Listener on cancel button on timePickerFragment?

Tags: android, listener

I'd use a TimePickerFragment to set a time and it works perfecly.

I'd just like to perform an action when the user click the "cancel" button.

Unfortunatly I didn't find how to do it so far.

Here is my code :

Create the dialog :

```
public void changeTime(int position) {
    df = new TimePickerFragment();
    df.setActivity(activity);
    df.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

    positionItemTime = position;

}
```

Perform an action when the user click on "set" :

```
public void setTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    visibleCursorNotes.moveToPosition(positionItemTime);

    int idSelectedRow = visibleCursorNotes.getInt(visibleCursorNotes.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    String content = visibleCursorNotes.getString(visibleCursorNotes.getColumnIndex("content_note"));

    String minuteString = "";
    String hourOfDayString = "";

    minuteString =  "" + minute;
    hourOfDayString = "" + hourOfDay;

    if (minute < 10){
        minuteString = "0" + minuteString;
    }

    if (hourOfDay < 10){
        hourOfDayString = "0" + hourOfDayString;
    }

    String time = "" + hourOfDayString + ":" + minuteString ;

    if (content.equals("")){
        content = "add note ...";
    }

    nds.updateNote(idSelectedRow, content, time);

    visibleCursorNotes = nds.getCursorUpdatedDatabaseForADate(visibleDate);
    updateData();

    visibleListView.setSelection(positionItemTime);

    activity.managerOfSound("write note");

}
```

Summarize : want to catch the click cancel button event to perform an action.

Thanks.

Comment: You try to catch the event of this fragment from the father view? or you catch the event inside the fragment?

Comment: This is in my activity that extends FragmentActivity

Comment: I think, If you want to catch the event of click the `button` in the father `activity` (the `activity` that your `TimePickerFragment` will be attached to), you have to create a `interface` inside the `TimePickerFragment`, then you have to `implements` the `interface` in your father activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, base on the override thing :

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
TimePickerDialog.OnDismissListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }


    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog){

        System.out.println("oui c'est très bon !");

    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        System.out.println("voila");
    }
}
```

The main part of the trick is to implement the TimePickerDialog.OnDismissListener and then to implement the function. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onCancel method to do that.

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
{
   super.onCancel(); 

   // do your action. you can have your own listener which will can be called.
}
```